# Rails.application.load_seed works but rake db:seed doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed, rails-console

What is the difference between rake environment and console environment?

I am trying to seed mysql database using csv file with rails 3.1.0.
It used to be a piece of cake with ActiveRecord::Fixtures. Unfortunately, csv fixture is depreciated in rails 3.1.

So I wrote load_fixture.rb in my config/initializers using csv-mapper 0.5.1. However, it does not work with

```
$ rake db:seed
```

The seed code runs without error. It just doesn't load any data.

When I copy the seed code into rails console or cucumber step, it works flawlessly. It even works with

```
> Rails.application.load_seed
```

in rails console. How can this happen?

load_fixture.rb:

```
require 'csv-mapper'
include CsvMapper
def load_fixture(file)
  fname = File.basename file.chomp(File.extname file)
  modelname = fname.camelize.singularize.constantize
  results = import(file) do
    map_to modelname
    after_row lambda{|row, item| item.save! } 
    start_at_row 1
    read_attributes_from_file     
  end
end
```

seed.rb (simplified)

```
load_fixture("path-to-csv-file")
```

Comment: You should tell use what "don't work" means in your context. It's difficult to help without knowing what kind of error you're facing

Comment: "don't work" means no data is saved to the database.